# Add applications to the original Android ROM

Tags: applications, stock-android, android-emulator, android-sdk

How can I add applications to the original Android ROM installed by manufacturer, and not lose them after a factory reset?

Comment: yes you can do it. but you have to root.

Answer (score 0):

NarenderNishad (via comments) is correct. If you have root access, you can convert the apps to system apps (using an app like Titanium Backup). They will be moved to the `/system` folder. When you do a factory reset, the apps will not be deleted.